# Bootstrap table with a sidebar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, html-table

I've been reading about the grid system and played around with my code over and over, but can't get the website to look like how I want it to. I want a sidebar next to a "content" area (basically a table).

**[Here is an image to help the visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPN1m.png)**.  Top is how my page looks now, and bottom is what I really it to look like.

This is proving difficult as I want a button to the top right of table. Can you critique my current code? Sorry it is rather messy, and I am a noob at Bootstrap.

Sidenote: This must be mobile compatible.

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="continer-fluid">
         <div class="row-fluid">
             <h2 class="col-sm-7">Your Off-Boarding Checklist</h2>
             <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-sm-1 pull-right" id="addtask" href="#">Add Task &raquo;</a>

             <table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped table-bordered col-sm-12">
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        Complete Paperwork
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
             </table>

            <div class="col-sm-3 pull-right container-fluid" id="sidebar">
               <h2>Your Last Day</h2>
               <h3>July 1, 2015</h3>
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've got some of the column classes on the wrong elements as @TomCat pointed out - maybe this will help:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Scrolling URL Hash</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Webpage for xxxx">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="continer-fluid">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-sm-7">
          <h2>Your Off-Boarding Checklist</h2>
          <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-sm-3 pull-right" id="addtask" href="#">Add Task &raquo;</a>
          <table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped table-bordered col-sm-12">
            <tr>
              <td>
              </td>
              <td>
                Complete Paperwork
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 pull-right container-fluid" id="sidebar">
          <h2>Your Last Day</h2>
          <h3>July 1, 2015</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Surround your `h2`, `a`, and `table` blocks with a single `div` having the classes `col-sm-9` and `pull-right`. Your sidebar `div` is not in a separate column from the rest of your page's content, and therefore the "Add task" button is getting floated to the right of the entire page, not just the column containing the to-do list items.